# Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, $a, b, c \in I$. Let $f(1)=0$, $f(7)\in (50,60)$ and $f(8)\in (70,80)$, then find the range of $f(2)$

Tags: functions

> **OPTIONS**
>
> A) $(-2,0)$
>
> B) $(0,10)$
>
> C) $(1,12)$
>
> D) $(20,30)$

From the first part, it is clear that
$$a+b+c=0$$
And
$$49a+7b+c\in (50,60)$$
$$64a+8b+c\in (70,80)$$

Subtracting them
$$15a+b\in (10,30)$$
While adding them gives $$113a+15b+2c\in (120,140)$$
$$111a+13b\in (120,140)$$

But we have to find the range of $$4a+2b+c$$
$$=3a+b$$

What should I do next?

Comment: Does "$a, b, c \in I$" mean that $a,b,c$ are integers?

Comment: @mathlove yes, they are integers

Comment: If the round brackets are inclusive, then since $48a+6b$ is an integer divisible by $6$, we get $48a+6b=54$ or $60$. Similarly, $63a+7b=70$ or $77$. Solving these gives $(a,b)=(2,-7),(1,2),(0,10),(1,1)$ implying $f(2)=-1,5,10,4$ respectively.

Comment: @mathlove that doesn’t match any option.

Comment: @mathlove As I've indicated in my answer comment, I've deleted my answer since I now believe the brackets were likely meant to be exclusive, so as your [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3583865/602049) shows, $f(2) = -1$ is the only solution, with this matching option A).

Comment: @John Omielan : Oh, I realize that my deleted answer is correct. So, now I've just undeleted my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Aditya : If we assume that the brackets are exclusive, then the only correct option is A). See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes that the round brackets are exclusive.

Since we have
$$f(1)=0\iff c=-a-b$$
we get
$$f(7)\in (50,60)\implies 48a+6b\in (50,60)$$
Since $48a+6b$ is an integer divisible by $6$, we get 
$$48a+6b=54\tag1$$
Similarly, we get
$$f(8)\in (70,80)\implies 63a+7b\in (70,80)$$
implying
$$63a+7b=77\tag2$$

It follows from $(1)(2)$ that $(a,b)=(2,-7)$.

Since we get $f(2)=-1$, the answer is option $\color{red}{A}$.